# Adjust Pivot Table Range - Google Sheets API

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to use the Google Sheets Node API to adjust the RANGE value. (See screenshot).

[image]

I have searched far and wide and can't seem to get an answer here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to set the source range of the pivot table using Sheets API with googleapis for Node.js.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth }); // Please use your client.

const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your spreadsheet ID.
const sheetIdOfPivotTable = "###"; // Please set sheet ID of pivit table.
const sheetIdOfSourceSheet = "###"; // Please set the sheet ID of the source sheet for your pivot table.

const requests = [
  {
    updateCells: {
      rows: [
        {
          values: [
            {
              pivotTable: {
                source: {
                  sheetId: sheetIdOfSourceSheet,
                  startRowIndex: 0,
                  endRowIndex: 10,
                  startColumnIndex: 0,
                  endColumnIndex: 3,
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      fields: "pivotTable.source",
      range: {
        sheetId: sheetIdOfPivotTable,
        startRowIndex: 14,
        endRowIndex: 15,
        startColumnIndex: 5,
        endColumnIndex: 6,
      },
    },
  },
];
await sheets.spreadsheets
  .batchUpdate({ spreadsheetId, resource: { requests } })
  .catch(({ errors }) => console.log(errors));
```

- When this script is run, the source range of the pivot table of "F15" of `sheetIdOfPivotTable` is updated to `A1:C10` of `sheetIdOfSourceSheet`.
- In this case, please set the range as the grid range. And, in this sample, it supposes that the pivot table is existing in the cell "F15" of `sheetIdOfPivotTable`. So, the range is as follows.

  ```json
  {
    sheetId: sheetIdOfPivotTable,
    startRowIndex: 14,
    endRowIndex: 15,
    startColumnIndex: 5,
    endColumnIndex: 6,
  }
  ```
- In this sample, it supposes that the following grid range of source range (you want to update) is used.

  ```json
  {
    sheetId: sheetIdOfSourceSheet,
    startRowIndex: 0,
    endRowIndex: 10,
    startColumnIndex: 0,
    endColumnIndex: 3,
  }
  ```

  - This grid range is used, `A1:C10` of a sheet of `sheetIdOfSourceSheet` is set as the source range.

#### References:

- [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)

Comment: Thank you for this helpful response. It seems to be working.

One more step is required though, which I thought would happen automatically but doesn't seem to be the case.

I need to add values under the "Rows" and "Values" column at the Pivot Table Editor so that the data can pull through. Is there a way to do this via the API?

Comment: @LukeVenter About `Thank you for this helpful response. It seems to be working`, I understood your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I need to add values under the "Rows" and "Values" column at the Pivot Table Editor so that the data can pull through. Is there a way to do this via the API?`, I would like to support you. But, this is different from your question. So, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Here is a link to that new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169514/add-parameters-to-google-sheets-pivot-table-with-sheets-api