# Add parameters to Google Sheets Pivot Table with sheets-api

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-api

I need to add values under the "Columns" and "Values" column at the Pivot Table Editor so that the data can pull through. Is there a way to do this via the google-sheets-api using Node?

See screenshots for the values that I need to update.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to add "Columns" and "Values" to a Pivot Table as shown in your question.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Node.js.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth }); // Please use your client.

const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your spreadsheet ID.
const sheetIdOfPivotTable = "###"; // Please set sheet ID of pivit table.
const sheetIdOfSourceSheet = "###"; // Please set the sheet ID of the source sheet for your pivot table.

const requests = [
  {
    updateCells: {
      rows: [
        {
          values: [
            {
              pivotTable: {
                source: {
                  sheetId: sheetIdOfSourceSheet,
                  startRowIndex: 0,
                  endRowIndex: 10,
                  startColumnIndex: 0,
                  endColumnIndex: 3,
                },
                columns: [
                  {
                    sourceColumnOffset: 0,
                    showTotals: true,
                    sortOrder: "ASCENDING",
                  },
                ],
                values: [
                  {
                    sourceColumnOffset: 0,
                    summarizeFunction: "SUM",
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      fields: "pivotTable.columns,pivotTable.values",
      range: {
        sheetId: sheetIdOfPivotTable,
        startRowIndex: 14,
        endRowIndex: 15,
        startColumnIndex: 5,
        endColumnIndex: 6,
      },
    },
  },
];
await sheets.spreadsheets
  .batchUpdate({ spreadsheetId, resource: { requests } })
  .catch(({ errors }) => console.log(errors));
```

- When this script is run, "Column" and "Value" are added to `pivotTable`. Please adjust `0` of `sourceColumnOffset: 0` in `columns` and `values` for your actual situation.
- In this case, it is required to include the source range in `pivotTable`. Please be careful about this.
- The values of `range` and `pivotTable.source` were used from your previous question. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76090761)

#### Note:

- **If your pivot table has already had several values in "Column" and "Value", please include them in the above request body. Because the above request body overwrites the existing values. Please be careful about this.**

#### References:

- [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)